# "Why don't we close these duplicates?" vs "Why do we not close these duplicates?" vs "Why do not we close these questions as duplicates?"

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I found a bunch of questions about these grammatical formulations:

1. "Why **don't** we close these duplicates?" (Negated question using a contraction)
2. "Why **do** we **not** close these duplicates?" (Negated question using full form, where **not** moves past the subject)
3. "Why **do not** we not close these duplicates?" (Negated question using full form, where **not** stays in place; considered archaic or ungrammatical by most people)

Not all the questions cover all 3 forms, but many do. Not all the questions have great titles either but that can be fixed.

---

### Usage

- [Expanding a contraction, where the expansion is not as it would seem](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/181147/191178)

  - My current canonical John Lawler answer. I chose it because I found it first, but I'm not sure if it's the best duplicate target
- [Can you say "are not we all?" instead of "aren't we all?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67822/191178)

  - Another John Lawler answer.
- [Is "Don't you know? " the same as "Do not you know?"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14287/191178)

  - I like the link in the answer two answers down, but not so much the other answers
- ["Do you not" vs. "Don't you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8372/191178)

  - Short and sweet and probably easier to understand for most people
- [Why do not we ask negative questions without a contraction on the not after the verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/212680/191178)

  - I like the answers on this, though they are pretty unfocused. The top answer talks about the history. The second answer is yet another John Lawler answer and one I like better than the other two JL answers
- [Is "aren't you too old to be..." proper grammar?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/372463/191178)

  - Everything downvoted. Has useful links in the comments
- [Why does "Why doesn't it work?" become "Why does it not work?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/82982/191178)

  - Sven Yargs points out that some people do say "Why does not..."
- [not or n't - word order in negative questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/458986/191178)
- [Why can I contract *across* a word, skipping the word in the middle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/253185/191178)
- [Shouldn't vs should not usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/528263/191178)
- [Why is "Why don't you like ___?" okay, but "Why do not you like?" ___?" isn't?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60952/191178)
- [Is this the right way to use "wouldn't"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/137349/191178)
- [How might one rewrite interrogative sentences with contractions, such as "Why can't we ... ", more elegantly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/345958/191178)
- [Tag Questions "is he not"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67355/191178)

  - About tag questions
- [Using abbreviations incorrectly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11250/191178)

  - Tag questions!
- [Using "aren't they"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/251841/191178)

  - Closed as GR, downvoted answer. About tag questions
- ["Is it not raining" vs. "Isn't it raining"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/82854/191178)

  - Closed as a duplicate, but is not about tag questions!
- [What is the correct usage of contractions like "isn't" and "wasn't"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/73994/191178)

  - Closed as a duplicate of a more generic contraction question
- https://english.stackexchange.com/q/590785/191178

  - Brand new question I closed as duplicate
- [is "weren't you..." considered grammatically correct? Because expanded, it would translate to "were not you..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/532254/191178)

  - Older Q I closed as a dupe
- ["Isn't that..." expanding to "Is not that..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/341671/191178)

  - Older Q I closed as a dupe
- ["Why can I not" vs. "Why can not I"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/237773/191178)

  - Closed

#### Differences in the correct forms

I don't remember if any of the questions above really explained the difference between the two correct forms, as opposed to just saying that they're both correct, so I put these in their own section.

- [Negative contractions in a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/419347/191178)

  - This doesn't ask about the ungrammatical third form. Does it need to be closed as a duplicate? Maybe, maybe not. I think it could use a stronger answer
- [Is it mandatory to use contractions in tag questions and the like?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/513499/191178)

  - This is about tag questions, and also doesn't ask about the ungrammatical third form.

### History

As I read more questions, it made sense to break this out into its own category. These questions aren't duplicates of any of the ones above. The answers are quite different between them so I'm not sure if it's useful to close all of them even as duplicates of each other. I think the questions could be polished a little though (weak titles).

- [Was "Do not you want to know..." correct 200 years ago, and is now incorrect?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/225666/191178)
- [negating contractions in Jane Austen](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/584900/191178)
- [Is it incorrect to say, "Why cannot....?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/50251/191178)
- [What is the origin of situations in which you cannot expand a contraction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/575364/191178)

### My questions

- What are the best canonicals in the "Usage" section?
- Should any of the history questions be closed as duplicates?
- What tags are best? I've been using [word-order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order)[questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions)[negation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negation)[contractions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contractions)[contraction-vs-full-form](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contraction-vs-full-form). For [tag-questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-questions), I guess I would replace [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions). (I may or may not retag many of these questions. But it seems appropriate to do so if I'm bumping with a reopen/reclose anyway.)
- Bonus: Does ELL have a canonical we can link to as well? (I may have to redo my searches there...)

Let's reach an agreement before closing or reopening any of these questions. I can do it easily myself with my unlimited well of mod closing powers.

Comment: Them's a lot of duplicates. How do we want to answer this? 4 separate answers, upvoted or downvoted to show favor? Or answers by individuals for all four?

Comment: @Mitch I suggest posting the suggestion that you agree with most. There's more than four ways to handle this, even if you only look at the "Usage" questions.

Comment: I have often thought that we should be reviewing  so-called  "duplicates" for quality: many older posts  would be closed in a heartbeat (given  current site policy and culture) as they are  not well-written and  have no accepted answer due to their LQ, yet they are considered canonical based only on their longevity...

Comment: First, let's define the question and what it refers to. Most of the OQs were normally incoherent, approaching constructions from every possible direction for every possible reason. If we're gonna have a Standard Answer, we oughta have a Good Question to fit it.

Comment: *Why do not we?* is very 19th-century, and I suspect that even when books printed that, authors expected it to be read as *Why don't we?* After 1750 there was a move away from phonetic spellings like *lov'd* in favour of morphological spellings like *loved*. I construe *Why do not we?* as an ultimately failed move in the same direction. A similar attempt to print spoken *can't* as *cannot* partly succeeded and left us with two different words. There are few reliable citations for *cannot* before 1700.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, the question has to do with fairly simple facts and rules. But these deal with several different things, and the various statements in the questions, and answers, are contradictory and confusing. So, as I suggested in my comment above, let's limit the question and state it clearly.

The topics involved are

1. question formation
2. subject-auxiliary inversion
3. auxiliary-negative contraction
4. the nature of negation and negative phrases

In order, Question Formation (both y/n and Wh) requires that there be an auxiliary before the subject. It also requires a lot of other stuff, but the position of the auxiliary before the subject is the point to concentrate here.

There are several ways to get an auxiliary in front of a subject. You can simply swap them:

- ***He was** working when she called* ==> ***Was he** working when she called?*

but if there isn't one, you hafta use *do* (the rule is called *Do*-Support) and put that in front of the subject:

- ***She** woke up at 3 am* ==> ***Did she** wake up at 3 am?*

That's all simple enough. But if you add a negative, you complicate the syntax. The usual place for *not* is after the first auxiliary verb (as usual, if there is no auxiliary verb, *Do*-Support happens)

- *Bill **is** eating lasagna*. + *not* ==> *Bill **is not** eating lasagna*.
- *Bill **ate** lasagna yesterday*. + *not* ==> *Bill **did not eat** lasagna yesterday.*

Since the first auxiliary verb carries the tense marker,  *Do*-Support changes the following verb to an infinitive (if it isn't one already), because *do* requires an infinitive complement. That's what happened to *ate* and *eat* above.

And that's simple enough, too, **except** that *not* has its own other uses;
[negation](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is never simple.

In modern English, *not* is contracted whenever possible. Avoiding a contraction marks the sentence as not standard, and can be used to emphasize something, though one is not always sure of what's being emphasized.

- He **hasn't** finished the painting yet.
- He **has not** finished the painting yet.

The second sentence above is more likely to have a different intonation, and to be interpreted as a complaint or recrimination.

But contraction with a negative reifies an auxiliary, and forms a new one. This new auxiliary must now be moved or not moved as a unit, and can't be split up. When a movement rule like Question Formation inverts an auxiliary, it moves the whole contraction:

- ***He has** not finished the painting*. ===> ***Has he** not finished the painting?*
- ***He hasn't** finished the painting*.  ===> ***Hasn't he** finished the painting?*

But it only moves the contracted auxiliary, not an uncontracted *not*, which stays where it is. Therefore there is no rule that generates the ungrammatical question

- **Has not he finished the painting?*

because there is no rule that unpacks *hasn't* to *has not* **after** it's been inverted. It only works in one direction, like a trapdoor function.

Comment: I didn't put in everything I could, but this does seem to me to settle the question reasonably well. Just how complete do you want this to be? It's not really an important question -- just ordinary syntax.

Comment: Is this what you want to post as an answer to whatever question we choose as the canonical? And do you have a suggestion for what question that would be (or if we should make a new one entirely)? Also, congrats on six digits (of rep)!

Comment: (It must have pissed off somebody; I got some hate mail and a lot of spam.) But I frankly didn't know how far to go here. This is what I consider a simple explanation of how those three sentences work out or don't, and why. There are many more misapprehensions I could apprehend, but I druther keep it simple; as I said, it isn't really a big issue. I don't care what you do with this answer; I was just trying to define the parameters of the question.